# Angular redirect to default child view

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following route configuration but I am getting the error `Invalid configuration of route 'tenant': redirectTo and children cannot be used together`

Once I have clicked /tenant I want to somehow show contents of both tenant followed by audit ? Is this possible ? My tenant URL looks like following `http://localhost:8080/#/tenant`

```js
{
    path: 'tenant',
    redirectTo: '/tenant/(view:audit)', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: TenantComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
        pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'audit',
            component: PacketDataComponent,
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
                pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

you can use an empty child route instead :

```js
{
    path: 'tenant',
    component: TenantComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'audit'
        },
        {
            path: 'audit',
            component: PacketDataComponent,
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
                pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This even works with the root module or nested modules for the root path of the module when specifying `path: ''`instead of `path: 'tenant'`.

Answer (score 2):

Heres my setup which seems to work ..

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {Route1Component} from './routes/route1/route1.component';
import {Route1DetailComponent} from './routes/route1/detail/route1-detail.component';
import {Route1ListComponent} from './routes/route1/list/route1-list.component';
import {Route2Component} from './routes/route2/route2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'route1',
    component: Route1Component,
    children: [
      {path: ':id', component: Route1DetailComponent},
      {path: '', component: Route1ListComponent}
    ]
  },
  {path: 'route2', component: Route2Component},
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    redirectTo: '/route1'
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Project at .. https://github.com/danday74/angular2-coverage/blob/master/app/app.routes.ts .. if you want to have a poke around

Heres another one ..

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {ParentRouteComponent} from './routes/parent-route/parent-route.component';
import {ChildRoute1Component} from './routes/parent-route/child-route-1/child-route-1.component';
import {ChildRoute2Component} from './routes/parent-route/child-route-2/child-route-2.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './routes/home/home.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './routes/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentRouteComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ChildRoute1Component,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ChildRoute2Component,
        data: {
          title: 'My title'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

taken from ..

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-router-simple/blob/master/app/app.routes.ts

Here the `**` route is the fallback and should be listed last.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to declare the route twice, one with the component and another with the redirectTo. Then in children routes, in the path, do not define the parent route. Like these:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

import { LoginViewComponent } from './views/login/login.cmp';
import { UserSearchViewComponent } from './views/userSearch/user-search.cmp';

import { SearchingByCriteriaViewComponent } from './views/userSearch/criteriaSearch/criteriaSearch.cmp';

import { InputsExampleViewComponent } from './views/inputsExample/example.cmp';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: LoginViewComponent },
  { path: 'busqueda',  redirectTo: 'busqueda/criterio', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'busqueda',  component: UserSearchViewComponent, children: [
    { path: 'criterio', component: SearchingByCriteriaViewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
  ] },
  { path: 'example',  component: InputsExampleViewComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```